# By changing values in one column based on condition in another column returns error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There is a df

```
request_type start_date  end_date

main         2020-02-12  2020-02-12
main         2020-02-12  2020-02-12
main         2020-02-12  2020-02-12
meta         2020-02-10  2020-02-10
meta         2020-02-10  2020-02-10
```

I need to add ' 00:00:00' to start_date and end_date column' values if request_type is main

What I tried is

```
df['start_date'] = np.where(df.request_type == 'main', df.start_date + ' 00:00:00', df.start_date)
```

I got this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

Ok then

```
df['start_date'] = np.where(df.request_type == 'main', df.start_date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' 00:00:00', df.start_date)
```

I got this error then

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Then I checked the type of start_date column and it is an object

I can't get where is an error and how to solve it

Appreciate any help

My ideal result is

```
request_type start_date           end_date

main         2020-02-12 00:00:00  2020-02-12 00:00:00
main         2020-02-12 00:00:00  2020-02-12 00:00:00
main         2020-02-12 00:00:00  2020-02-12 00:00:00
meta         2020-02-10           2020-02-10
meta         2020-02-10           2020-02-10
```

Comment: What is reason for this? Why need append `00:00:00` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but get mixed values - strings with `00:00:00` and python dates objects in one column, so next processing should be problematic:

```
df['start_date'] = np.where(df.request_type == 'main', 
                            pd.to_datetime(df.start_date).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'),
                            df.start_date)
```

Or:

```
df['start_date'] = np.where(df.request_type == 'main', 
                            df.start_date.astype(str) +' 00:00:00',
                            df.start_date)
```

---

```
print (df)
  request_type           start_date    end_date
0         main  2020-02-12 00:00:00  2020-02-12
1         main  2020-02-12 00:00:00  2020-02-12
2         main  2020-02-12 00:00:00  2020-02-12
3         meta           2020-02-10  2020-02-10
4         meta           2020-02-10  2020-02-10

print (df['start_date'].apply(type))
0              <class 'str'>
1              <class 'str'>
2              <class 'str'>
3    <class 'datetime.date'>
4    <class 'datetime.date'>
Name: start_date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need